What is not priced in - Trading Strategies
When it comes to trading strategies I get the feeling that whenever I read about a strategy in a book or when I have view, all of that is already priced in and does not make a case for a good trading strategy.
Example: Before a Fed meeting, say markets expect a rate cut. I would have naively assumed that the 1Y swap rate for example going down. However it turns out that this is already priced in, which renders where the rate is going after the Fed meeting hard to predict. Or in general, I whenever I think something will drive the priced, I also think but wait this is priced in.
My question is, what is not priced in yet, or how to find the thing that is not priced in?

Not a trading strategies expert, but thinking from a probability-based perspective, I don't think it is a matter of priced in or not (in terms of binary), but people will make trading decisions or "price it in" the asset with their own subjective level of certainty. That is why even when stocks are anticipating a merger, after the merger successfully completes (and long after the announcement), there is still that mediocre level of price bump.

Most commentary is usually derived from price action therefore by definition is just telling you what is priced/consensus view. Some hypotheses like PEH for example, if the YC is downward sloping the mkt expects cuts. By receiving swaps you will carry/roll  negatively, resulting in breaking even unless the mkt outperforms that carry. If you go out further than immediate hikes/cuts then there is more scope to be right/wrong but also a larger variance and time to convergence for.your view (if it were right to begin with).

You select event studies, find an event and use one of the accepted event study methodologies, their is software in R, and SImon Beninga's book Finance with excel has a demonstration of using excel for event studies, it is also one of the modules of the Coursera course from Georgia Tech; Computational investing part 1 with python.

Event studies are a cornerstone of arbitrage trading and go back as far as the sixties, it is a well defined and common technique. The fed is one of the most studied and documented event studies there is as well as dividend and Earnings announcements. A bit of simple research should yield a lot of information.

It is not a great strategy I assure you being so obvious and common.
